# android onCheckedChanged for radiogroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I'm writing an `Activity` in android where I have two radio buttons under a RadioGroup. One of them is checked by default. But I can't trigger the event in `onCreate` method so that I can do something in that. The `onCheckedChanged` is running fine when clicked on.

```
RadioGroup ItemtypeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rechargeItemtype);
    RadioButton providerRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a);
    providerRadio.performClick();

    ItemtypeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group,int checkedId){

            Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

            if (checkedId == R.id.a) {
                //some code
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.b) {
                //some code
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try putting your `performClick()` code after you set the `listener`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but no luck :(

Comment: Hmmm...have you put a breakpoint inside your `listener` to be sure that it isn't going there and something else inside it isn't screwing it up?

Comment: edited. When i click on the radio i can see the effect in the logcat.

Answer (score 48):

To fire a radio check box for the default when initializing.  Set everything to unchecked with the clearCheck method, then set the handler, then set the default and your handler will fire.

```
itemtypeGroup.clearCheck();
```

then same as usual add a listener...

```
itemtypeGroup
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

                if (checkedId == R.id.a) {
                    //some code
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.b) {
                    //some code
                }

            }

        });
```

Then check the default radio button and your listener will fire.

```
rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.a);
rb.setChecked(true);
```

Good Luck

Comment: What does this "rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.a);" mean? Do we have to declare inside onCheckedChanged?

Comment: Three steps.  Clear all, wire up handler, set default.   Because the default is set after the listener is wired up the listener code will run.

Comment: I am sorry for the downvote - it was inadvertent. I tried to correct it by clicking upvote, but I could not. If you know of a way to correct the downvote, please let me know.

Comment: NP don't worry about it.

Comment: Suppose I have three radio groups, then how would I handle the listener for three of them?

Comment: @Jorvis For three groups+ I might use a switch statement on checkedID.  Plan all of the checkedIds are unique in the APP.  I might use separate handlers depends on app I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
             //do work when radioButton1 is active
            } else  if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
             //do work when radioButton2 is active
          } else  if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton3) {
             //do work when radioButton3 is active
          }

        }
    });
```

this work for me . hope is helpfull

Comment: Suppose I have three radio groups, then how would I handle the listener for three of them?

Comment: So you mean I should implement three different listeners along with three onCheckedChanged methods for three radio groups.

Comment: no. you must be use one Listener and check which one selected in listener.

Answer (score 6):

Try this Code.

Declare this code in your onCreate method.

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radioGroup.clearCheck();
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (null != rb && checkedId > -1) {

                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.one:
                     // Do Something
                      break;

                    case R.id.two:
                    // Do Something
                      break;   

                    case R.id.three:
                    // Do Something   
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is because, you are setting** `OnCheckedChangeListener` **on** `RadioGroup` **after the** `providerRadio.performClick();` **method call**.
That's why when `providerRadio.performClick();` method executes till then their is no `OnCheckedChangeListener` available to call. So, to make it work, you need to set Listener before the call to `performClick()` method.

And instead of using `RadioButton.performClick()` you should use `RadioGroup.check()` method to change the current checked `RadioButton`.

So you can use this code to change current selection of RadioGroup

```
RadioGroup ItemtypeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rechargeItemtype);
ItemtypeGroup
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

                if (checkedId == R.id.a) {
                    //some code
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.b) {
                    //some code
                }

            }

        });
ItemtypeGroup.check(R.id.a);
```

**Note**:- 
**Make sure to call** `RadioGroup.check()` **method after adding** `OnCheckedChangeListener` **as above in code snippet.**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are performing click before setting listener to the group, that's why event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Even though [@dannys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537931/) is ok I would like to have the **default value** taken **from** the **XML** layout definition file rather then setting it in code.

That's why I use this approach to:

1. store the default value form the radio group
2. clear all check's
3. initialize the `OnCheckedChangeListener`
4. check the default again (which was stored previously) which triggers the listener

This could look like this in code with the `first_radio_button` as the **default** radio button:

```
// call this in any init method
_myRadioGroup    = _myViewContainingTheRadioGroup.findViewById(R.id.my_radio_group);
int defaultValue = _myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
_myRadioGroup.clearCheck();
_myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(_myRadioGroupCheckedChangeListener);
_myRadioGroup.check(defaultValue);
```

Place the `OnCheckedChangeListener` somewhere in your class:

```
private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener _myRadioGroupCheckedChangeListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
  {
    switch(group.findViewById(checkedId).getId())
    {
      case R.id.first_radio_button:
        // do stuff
        break;
      case R.id.second_radio_button:
        // do stuff
        break;
      // ...
    }
  }
};
```

This is my radio group xml

```
  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/my_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/first_radio_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:checked="true"
      android:text="@string/first_radio_button_text"/>

    <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/second_radio_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="@string/second_radio_button_text"/>

    // ...

  </RadioGroup>
```