# setting radio button for different task

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiobutton

I am trying to show radio group in a dialog and when the radio button is clicked it will set some data in shared preference. I am able to make toast when any button is clicked but I want to do something when different button is clicked .I tried setting Onclick in the radio button but it is not working .I am trying to learn from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)
this is my dialog class

```
 public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes, no;
public RadioGroup radioGroup;
public RadioButton radioButton;

public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);
    Radioactive();
}

private void Radioactive() {
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);




}
```

I just want to know how to do some thing when specific radio button is checked.

Comment: Are all your `RadioButton`s within `RadioGroup` tag and have separate IDs? Also, the `RadioActive()` should be inside the `onClick()` method so, share that too

Comment: ya all are under RadioGroup with different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the radio button click as follows.
 For more details [android onCheckedChanged for radiogroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536195/android-oncheckedchanged-for-radiogroup)
for different function

```
radioGroup
    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
 Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

            if (checkedId == R.id.a) {
                //some code
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.b) {
                //some code
            }

        }

    });
```